# Why does the create account button not appear on guest checkout success page

Tags: magento2.2, guest-checkout, registration

I have a Magento 2.2 site that I have been building, however for some reason the "create account" button does not appear on the checkout success page. There is however an error in the dev tools console.

```
customer-data.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
'sectionLoadUrl' of undefined
at Object.getFromServer (customer-data.js:85)
at Object.reload (customer-data.js:299)
at (index):610
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
at Module.check (require.js:866)
at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
at require.js:132
at require.js:1156
at each (require.js:57)
at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
```